# Changing JSON Structure in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an object coming from the server via JSON which is in the below format. I want to rearrange it to another format.

```
{
    visits: [{
        week: 1,
        count: 3
    }, {
        week: 2,
        count: 3
    }, {
        week: 3,
        count: 4
    }, {
        week: 4,
        count: 3
    }, {
        week: 5,
        count: 1
    }],
    visitors: [{
        week: 1,
        count: 3
    }, {
        week: 2,
        count: 3
    }, {
        week: 3,
        count: 4
    }, {
        week: 4,
        count: 3
    }, {
        week: 5,
        count: 1
    }]
}
```

I want to change its structure and want this format below:

```
{
    week1: {
        visits: 3
        visitors: 1
    }
    week2: {
        visits: 3
        visitors: 3
    }
    week3: {
        visits: 4
        visitors: 4
    }
    week4: {
        visits: 3
        visitors: 3
    }
    week5: {
        visits: 4
        visitors: 4
    }
}
```

Comment: What have ***you*** tried? Any code to share?

Comment: That's not JSON, and even if you get the data as JSON, it's irrelevant for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var newObj = {}

$.each(a.visits, function(key,obj){ newObj['week'+obj.week] ={visits: obj.count} });

$.each(a.visitors, function(key,obj){ newObj['week'+obj.week].visitors = obj.count});
```

Answer (score 0):

so use groupBy feature :

```
var groupBy=function(jsonArray,key) {
      return jsonArray.reduce(function(rv, x) {
        (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
        return rv;
      }, {});
   };
```

Then :

```
var groupedByWeeks=groupBy(yourJsonArray.visits,'week')
```

then map the object `1->week1`, .. `n->weekn`

```
Object.keys(groupedByWeeks).map((k)=>
     groupedByWeeks['week'+k]=groupedByWeeks[k];
)
```